# Adding drop shadows to carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I came across this [really cool theme](https://pixelarity.com/transition), I like the drop shadow that this site uses for the carousel, I have no clue how this is being accomplished though.

I can create an inner shadow on the my carousel with css but it looks nothing like this. Anyone able to accomplish something like this? Perhaps its not using css but rather a transparent png, not sure cause I cant read the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Just inspected it and here's the css

```
#main .previous {
    background-image: url("assets/css/images/shadow.png");
    left: 0;
}
```